# How is rating score calculated on Lichess?

Tags: rating, lichess

I've recently lost to a 1500 player. My rating is about 1200. Ironically, he got 163 points. How is it possible for a 1500 player to gain more points on a lower-rated player? The system that Lichess uses to calculate rating scores is very confusing. How is it done?

Comment: Could be the opponent's rating was still provisional.

Comment: See: [What rating system does Lichess use?](https://lichess.org/faq#ratings), [Why is there a question mark (?) next to a rating?](https://lichess.org/faq#provisional) from the official lichess FAQ.

Comment: do you have a link? even if provisional +163? come on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without the link to player profiles and the game iteself, it is difficult to say for certain exactly what happened.

For one, Lichess starts new users with a rating of 1500.<sup>[1]</sup>

Even if your opponent didn't have a 1500 rating, as [double-beep points out](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/38699/how-is-rating-score-calculated-on-lichess/38700#comment61678_38699) Lichess uses the Glicko-2 rating system<sup>[2]</sup> which explicitly tracks the player's **rating**, a **rating deviation**, and a **rating volatility**. The system views a player's rating from a stochastic perspective, as an interval not a single point value.<sup>[1]</sup>

The system will detect and provide a larger rating change in various circumstances including:

- "exceptionally strong results after period of stability",<sup>[3]</sup> or
- after a period of inactivity (it is less certain if rating is still accurate).

The Glicko-2 creator, Dr. Mark Glickman, provides the mathematical formulas for the system.<sup>[3,4]</sup>

**As an example**, consider [this classical game](https://lichess.org/LElAJZxq) on Lichess. At the time of the game, the player with the White pieces had only played 1 rapid game. The system seeded the player (White) with a 1500 rating but annotated it as *1500?* to denote the provisional rating.

References:
<sub>[1] [Chess Rating Systems](https://lichess.org/page/rating-systems), Lichess website.</sub>
<sub>[2] [What rating system does Lichess use?](https://lichess.org/faq#ratings), Lichess FAQ page.</sub>
<sub>[3] [Example of the Glicko-2 System](http://www.glicko.net/glicko/glicko2.pdf), ME Glickman, 30 Nov 2013.</sub>
<sub>[4] http://www.glicko.net/glicko.html, website by Mark E. Glickman.</sub>